# Input range doesn't update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the input range. 
When I add a new accordion panel, the input range takes the value from the first one and I can't set a new one. 
https://jsfiddle.net/agata666/hu1cvy5n/17/

```
var $foo = $(".foo");
var hash = 1;
$(".add").on("click", function () {
    var $newPanel = $foo.clone();
    var hashClass = 'zone-panel-' + generateHash();
    $newPanel.find(".collapse").removeClass("in");
    $newPanel.find(".accordion-toggle").data('hash', hashClass).attr("href",  "#" + (++hash)).text("panel " + hash);
    $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", hash).addClass("collapse").removeClass("in");
    $($newPanel).addClass(hashClass);
    $("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());

});

var sliderOne = document.querySelector(".abc");
var outputOne = document.querySelector(".one");
sliderOne.oninput = function() {
    outputOne.innerHTML = sliderOne.value + '%';
}


var panelDefault = document.querySelectorAll('.panel-default');
var addZoneButton = document.getElementById('add');

function generateHash(){
    return Math.random().toString(16).substr(-5);
}

addZoneButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var randomNumber = generateHash();
    panelDefault.innerHTML = 'panel panel-default foo template ' + randomNumber;

});
```

`
Could you help me?

Comment: @htshame Your snippet gives an error making it useless.

Comment: @MarkBaijens that's odd, because it worked in preview

Comment: @MarkBaijens Thanks Mark, I shouldn't have added the jquery tag. Still I do not know what to do with this input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event handlers do not get copied. However jQuery does have a `clone()` function. It accepts a boolean to copy event handlers too. You can do this with the clone function of jQuery pretty easily.

- `clone()` or `clone(false)` or `clone(false, false)` Creates a clone of your selection without event handlers.
- `clone(true)` or `clone(true, true)` Creates a clone of your selection with event handlers including the event handlers of child elements
- `clone(true, false)` Creates a clone of your selection with event handlers but not the event handlers for the child elements.

Here is an example.

```js
$(function(){

  //Onchange event handler to copy the value to a div to show to the user.
  $('.slider').on('change', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.slider_value').text($(this).val());
  });
  
  //Click event handler to clone a slider including event handlers and add to the html w
  $('#add').on('click', function(){
    $('.slider_wrapper').first().clone(true).appendTo('#sliders');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sliders">
  <div class="slider_wrapper">
    <div class="slider_value">1</div>
    <input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="15"/>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: @agata666 Please accept this as an answer if this solved your problem.